# JOIN two CTE to create a summary using GROUP BY

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a CTE called open_bridges whose first 24 rows are shown below.

| Structure Type | Year Built | Structure Code | Status Granted Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BRIDGE | 1958 | F | 12/6/2016 |
| TUNNEL | 1961 | L | 3/28/2022 |
| BRIDGE | 1999 | F | 1/9/2002 |
| RWALL | 1998 | I | 4/17/2000 |
| BRIDGE | 2014 | F | 11/7/2018 |
| BRIDGE | 2017 | G | 5/08/2020 |
| BRIDGE | 2012 | K | 1/9/2017 |
| RWALL | 2003 | F | 3/07/2007 |
| BRIDGE | 1999 | F | 2/24/2011 |
| BRIDGE | 2006 | K | 6/02/2017 |
| BRIDGE | 2008 | F | 9/24/2019 |
| TUNNEL | 2000 | F | 4/17/2016 |
| TUNNEL | 2011 | I | 11/7/2018 |
| BRIDGE | 2013 | G | 5/08/2020 |
| BRIDGE | 2017 | F | 1/9/2020 |
| RWALL | 2003 | F | 3/07/2005 |
| TUNNEL | 2011 | I | 11/7/2018 |
| BRIDGE | 2013 | G | 5/08/2020 |
| BRIDGE | 2017 | F | 1/9/2020 |
| RWALL | 2003 | F | 3/07/2005 |
| TUNNEL | 2016 | K | 12/5/2019 |
| RWALL | 2014 | F | 8/05/2016 |
| RWALL | 2015 | F | 1/9/2021 |
| BRIDGE | 2017 | K | 3/03/2022 |

I use the following SQL Developer query to get the following result:

```
SELECT 
            
      oba.Structure_type,
            
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2016' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2016,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2017' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2017,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2018' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2018,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2019' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2019,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2020' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2020,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2021' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2021,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2022' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2022,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2023' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2023
            
    FROM open_bridges oba 
   
    
    GROUP BY oba.structure_type,gika.structure_type
    ORDER BY oba.structure_type DESC
```

The result is:

| Structure_type | y2016 | y2017 | y2018 | y2019 | y2020 | y2021 | y2022 | y2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TUNNEL | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| RWALL | 5 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| BRIDGE | 6 | 10 | 12 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 |

Then I run another SQL query:

```
SELECT 
            
            gika.Structure_type,
            
            SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM gika.status_granted_date) >='2016' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS gik2016

FROM gikl_all_strucs gika
GROUP BY gika.structure_type
```

I get following result:

| Structure_type | gik2016 |
| --- | --- |
| BRIDGE | 13 |
| RWALL | 5 |
| TUNNEL | 4 |

However, its combining both results that gives wrong values.

The SQL query I tried is as follows:

```
SELECT 
            
     oba.STructure_type,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2016' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2016,
     SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM gika.current_status_granted_date) >='2016' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS gik2016,            
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2017' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2017,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2018' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2018,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2019' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2019,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2020' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2020,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2021' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2021,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2022' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2022,
     SUM(CASE WHEN oba.YEAR_BUILT<='2023' OR oba.YEAR_BUILT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2023
             
FROM open_bridges oba LEFT JOIN gikl_all_strucs gika 
                ON oba.structure_type=gika.structure_type 
                        AND oba.structure_no=gika.structure_no 
                        AND oba.year_built=gika.year_built 
                        AND oba.structure_status_type_code=gika.structure_status_type_code
    
    
    GROUP BY oba.structure_type
    ORDER BY oba.structure_type DESC
```

and the result I get is:

| Structure_type | y2016 | gik2016 | y2017 | y2018 | y2019 | y2020 | y2021 | y2022 | y2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TUNNEL | 3 | 0 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| RWALL | 5 | 0 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| BRIDGE | 6 | 0 | 12 | 12 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 |

I get '0' in gik2016 column.

Can anyone please assist me in rectifying my SQL query so I can get the following result:

| Structure_type | y2016 | gik2016 | y2017 | y2018 | y2019 | y2020 | y2021 | y2022 | y2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TUNNEL | 3 | 13 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| RWALL | 5 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| BRIDGE | 6 | 4 | 12 | 12 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 |

*Please note that open_bridge and gikl_all_strucs are two CTEs derived from the same table. The only difference is a WHERE caluse. open_bridge deals with structure type IN ('F') whereas gikl_all_strucs is structure type IN ('G','I','K','L').

I shall be obliged if some one can help me write a SQL query to get the result I want.

My apologies if I am not able to explain my question properly. If you require more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` both tables together and then pivot:

```sql
SELECT Structure_type,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'GAS' AND year_built >=2016 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS gik2016
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OB' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2016 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2016,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OB' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2017 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2017,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OB' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2018 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2018,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OB' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2019 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2019,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OB' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2020 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2020,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OB' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2021 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2021,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OB' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2022 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2022,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OB' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2023 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2023
FROM   (
  SELECT structure_type,
         year_built,
         'OB' AS type
  FROM   open_bridges
  UNION ALL
  SELECT structure_type,
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM status_granted_date),
         'GAS'
  FROM   gikl_all_strucs
  WHERE  status_granted_date >= DATE '2016-01-01'
)
GROUP BY
      structure_type
```

Or, if both `open_bridges` and `gikl_all_strucs` are views based on the same table then just use the base table:

```sql
SELECT Structure_type,
       SUM(CASE WHEN structure_type IN ('G','I','K','L') AND year_built >=2016 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS gik2016
       SUM(CASE WHEN structure_type = 'F' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2016 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2016,
       SUM(CASE WHEN structure_type = 'F' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2017 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2017,
       SUM(CASE WHEN structure_type = 'F' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2018 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2018,
       SUM(CASE WHEN structure_type = 'F' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2019 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2019,
       SUM(CASE WHEN structure_type = 'F' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2020 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2020,
       SUM(CASE WHEN structure_type = 'F' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2021 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2021,
       SUM(CASE WHEN structure_type = 'F' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2022 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2022,
       SUM(CASE WHEN structure_type = 'F' AND (YEAR_BUILT<=2023 OR YEAR_BUILT IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y2023
FROM   your_base_table
GROUP BY
      structure_type
```